Need return context info
needs your help for the problem I am encountering a weeks now. For the context, I am sending a message to another MQ by simply sending the BLOB message only and then they will reply to my local queue with BLOB. My local queue will pick it up and format it as JSON and send via HTTP Reply. On the HTTP Reply, I need to return the httpId which located from the BLOB response and it is the leading 8 characters. After checking the logs, I get an error from the Response saying "Need return context info".
My response structure flow is below:
MQ node ---> Compute node ----> HTTP Reply ---> Log node
My Compute node code:
BROKER SCHEMA response Path shared;

CREATE COMPUTE MODULE PolicyUpdateResponse
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        
        DECLARE httpId BLOB SUBSTRING(CAST(InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB AS CHARACTER CCSID 1208) FROM 1 FOR 8);
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.ReplyIdentifier = CAST(httpId AS BLOB CCSID 1208);
        
        SET OutputRoot.Properties.MessageFormat = '';
        SET OutputRoot.JSON = InputBody;
        
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.Status = 'Success';
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.Message = CAST(InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB AS CHARACTER CCSID 1208);       
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;            
    
END MODULE;


I hope the issue is resolved, but if someone else is reading this, please make sure to validate what is being put by the source in the queue is BLOB is the same is what being received.
So in the debugger if the reply identifer on the source before putting message  is showing as: X'0123456789ABCDEF'
Then on the other side, it should also show up X'0123456789ABCDEF' in the debugger. I alway recommend to convert a blob data to text before putting it in the queue to avoid data hampering when it's being transferred b/w any MQ layer.
Moreover, the reply idenfier is auto generated as soon as the message lands on the HTTP Input terminal and the same reply identifer must be provided when sending the reply so that the reply goes to the actual caller, You're using the initial 8 characters of the payload as reply identifer, I think there's a gap in your understanding of Reply identifer.
